# What does "adresser un pot de confiture à l'aigreur de la situation" mean?

Tags: sens, traduction, expressions-idiomatiques

[Nietzsche : "J’adresse un pot de confiture pour me débarrasser d’une histoire qui tourne au vinaigre."](https://www.franceculture.fr/emissions/3-minutes-de-philosophie-pour-redevenir-humain/nietzsche)

What is meant by the expression *adresser un pot de confiture*? Especially the word *adresser* has me confused in this context. Does someone know a similar English expression?

Comment: Nietszche was German and the English translation for the  German is: I dispatch a pot of jam in order to get rid of a bitter experience. But there have been many translations of his work. He was not French so the French is a translation,too.

Comment: This is a case of bad translation; it’s a shame France Culture used it. “Adresser” requires an indirect objet (“addresser” to whom?), absent here; and its direct object should be a letter, a package, something that naturally has a destination (otherwise, we’d say “envoyer”). I had to listen to the podcast in order to understand what that title meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your question is  [here](https://www.franceculture.fr/emissions/3-minutes-de-philosophie-pour-redevenir-humain/nietzsche).

The author is personnalising "l'aigreur" (the sourness) and sending figuratively something to it so as to sweeten it.

Here is a spoken detailed explanation of this thought of Nietzsche's: [pot de confiture](https://player.fm/series/3-minutes-de-philosophie-pour-redevenir-humain/nietzsche-jadresse-un-pot-de-confiture-pour-me-debarrasser-dune-histoire-qui-tourne-au-vinaigre). It is spoken in French but it is well developed and articulated, a good exercise.

Answer (score 5):

The original German from *Ecce Homo* is :

- > Im gleichniss geredet: ich schicke einen Topf mit Confitüren, um eine sauere Geschichte loszuwerden.

*Schicken* you can translate in French as *envoyer* or *send* in English.  However *schicken* can also mean *zu Boden schicken*, *jeter à terre*, *jeter par terre*.  That's how Henri Albert, Nietzsche's first translator in French, understood it :

- > Pour m’exprimer en image, je jette un pot de confitures pour me débarrasser de l’aigreur.

Here's the passage where this is taken from, Nietzsche's text followed by Henri Albert's translation :

- > Gleich jedem, der nie unter seines Gleichen lebte und dem der Begriff »Vergeltung« so unzugänglich ist wie etwa der Begriff »gleiche
  >   Rechte«, verbiete ich mir in Fällen, wo eine kleine oder sehr
  >   grosse Torheit an mir begangen wird, jede Gegenmaßregel, jede Schutzmaßregel, - wie billig, auch jede Verteidigung, jede »Rechtfertigung«. Meine Art Vergeltung besteht darin, der Dummheit so schnell wie möglich eine Klugheit nachzuschicken: so holt man sie vielleicht noch ein. **Im Gleichniss geredet: ich schicke einen Topf mit Confitüren, um eine sauere Geschichte loszuwerden.**
- > Comme tous ceux qui n’ont jamais vécu parmi leurs pareils et chez qui l’idée de « représailles » est aussi inconnue que celle de « droits égaux », je m’interdis, dans les cas où l’on m’a causé un tort léger ou même un grand préjudice, toute mesure de sûreté ou de protection et, comme de juste, aussi toute défense, toute « justification » . Ma réplique consiste à faire suivre aussi vite que possible la sottise par une malice. De la sorte on parvient peut-être à se rattraper. **Pour m’exprimer en image, je jette un pot de confitures pour me débarrasser de *l’aigreur*.**

Here's the traslation of Alexandre Vialatte, Kafka's first translator in French :

- > Comme tous ceux qui n'ont jamais vécu parmi leurs pairs et auxquels l'idée de « représailles » demeure aussi étrangère que celle de « droits égaux », je m'interdis, dans les cas où l'on commet contre moi une sottise, petite ou grande, toute mesure de représailles ou de protection, comme aussi toute défense, toute « justification». Ma façon de riposter consiste à faire suivre la bêtise aussi vite que possible d'une chose intelligente : c'est la seule méthode qui donne des chances de la rattraper. **Pour employer une image : j'envoie un pot de confiture à mon adversaire pour le débarrasser de son aigreur.**

Pour rigoler un peu, voici les traductions que nous proposent respectivement *google translate* et *deepl*, deux logiciels de traduction.

- Comme toute personne qui n'a jamais vécu sous son égalité et qui a le concept de "rétribution" aussi inaccessible que le concept d'"égalité des droits", je m'interdis de faire toute contre-mesure, tout cas où une folie petite ou très grande est commise envers moi Mesure de protection, ainsi que tout moyen de défense, toute justification. Mon genre de rétribution est de renvoyer la bêtise à la sagesse le plus rapidement possible: ils peuvent vous rattraper. **Dans la parabole, j'envoie un pot de confiture pour se débarrasser d'une histoire de l'acide.**  GOOGLE TRANSLATE
- Comme tous ceux qui n'ont jamais vécu parmi ses pairs et pour qui le terme "représailles" est aussi inaccessible que le terme "égalité des droits", je m'interdis de me défendre dans les cas où une petite ou très grande folie est commise contre moi, toute contre-mesure, toute mesure de protection, - combien bon marché, aussi toute défense, toute "justification. Mon genre de représailles consiste à envoyer le plus vite possible une sagesse à la stupidité : on pourrait ainsi la rattraper. **Parlé en parabole : J'envoie un pot de confitures pour me débarrasser d'une histoire aigre.**  DEEPL

Comme on peut le voir, il y a encore du boulot avant que la si mal nommée intelligence artificielle mette les traducteurs au chômage !

Comment: Très intéressant la comparaison des 2 traductions. Et merci d'avoir mis l'allemand.